# Type 'ReadCitee' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a little problem. I try to add the results of my database in a dynamic list but I get the error message "type 'ReadCitee' is not a subtype of type 'String' ". I tried to return an object of type String in my "READCITEE" class but this one only wants to return objects of type widgets. I have been stuck for several days. Thank you for the help in advance.

My class PageVille:

```
import 'package:ampc93/fonction/firebase_crud/add_citee.dart';
import 'package:ampc93/fonction/firebase_crud/read_citee.dart';
import 'package:ampc93/page_cite.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageVille extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? titre;

  PageVille(this.titre);

  @override
  _PageVilleState createState() => _PageVilleState();
}

class _PageVilleState extends State<PageVille> {
  TextEditingController citeeController = TextEditingController();

  var citeesList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    citeesList.add(ReadCitee(widget.titre!));
  }

  Future<void> displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: TextField(
              controller: citeeController,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
              decoration:
                  InputDecoration(hintText: "Entrez une nouvelle citée"),
            ),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  child: Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    AddCitee().addCitee(widget.titre!, citeeController.text);
                    setState(() {
                      citeesList.add(citeeController.text);
                      citeeController.clear();
                    });
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  citeeController.clear();
                },
                child: Text("Annuler"),
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.titre!),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text(citeesList[index]),
                    onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => PageCite(citeesList[index]))),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                        color: Colors.red[300],
                        iconSize: 32,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            citeesList.remove(citeesList[index]);
                          });
                        }));
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
              itemCount: citeesList.length)),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => displayDialog(context),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[300],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Class ReadCitee:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReadCitee extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;

  ReadCitee(this.documentId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('citee');
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Something ent wrong");
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
            return Text("Documents does not exist");
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            print("Ca marche");
            return Text("Full name: ${data['Nom']}");
          }
          return Text("Loading");
        });
  }
}
```

The error:

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'ReadCitee' is not a subtype of type 'String'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _PageVilleState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:ampc93/page_ville.dart:72
#1      new ListView.separated.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_view.dart:1277
#2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:455
#3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build
package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:1201
#4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement
package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:1145
...
```

Comment: Please provide full stacktrace of error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `build` method of `_PageVileeState`, there is the following code:

```dart
return ListTile(
  title: Text(citeesList[index]),
  onTap: () => Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => PageCite(citeesList[index]))),
  trailing: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
    color: Colors.red[300],
    iconSize: 32,
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() => citeesList.remove(citeesList[index]));
    },
  ),
);
```

The `Text` expects a `String` in its constructor. You're passing a `citeesList[index]`. A `citeesList` is a `List<ReadCitee>`, not a `List<String>`. Therefore, `citeesList[index]` is a `ReadCitee`, not a `String`, thus the error. I don't know what's the logic behind your code, but to fix it you can replace

```dart
title: Text(citeesList[index]),
```

with the following, if you want a `Text` with the `documentId` as content:

```dart
title: Text(citeesList[index].documentId),
```

or the following, if you want the `ReadCitee` itself as the `ListTile`'s title:

```dart
title: citeesList[index],
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, that was it